# How do you write an htaccess RewriteRule to match hyphen characters?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to convert all php files in the imi directory to html

.htaccess rules:

```
RewriteRule ^imi/([0-9|a-z]*).html$ imi/$1.php
```

**The following rewrite correctly:**

- Imi/abc.php to imi/abc.html
- Imi/6s.php to imi/6s.html
- Imi/hi4.php to imi/hi4.html
- Imi/5.php to imi/5.html
- Imi/ho12bc.php to imi/ho12bc.html
- Imi/miss.php to imi/miss.html

**Whereas these don't:**

- Imi/abc-1.php to imi/abc-1.html
- Imi/6s-my.php to imi/6s-my.html
- Imi/hi4-oe-5.php to imi/hi4-oe-5.html
- Imi/5-lb.php to imi/5-lb.html
- Imi/ho12bc-123-us.php to imi/ho12bc-123-us.html
- Imi/miss-sir.php to imi/miss-sir.html

Why do the addresses with `-` not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rewrite rule should include the hyphen as the first character in the matching pattern. Also, you shouldn't need the pipe character in there. Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^imi/([-0-9a-z]*).html$ imi/$1.php
```

Comment: Finally, using this code, it was successful `RewriteRule ^moonlol/(.+)\.html$ moonlol/$1.php`